# std::enable_if an argument is a function?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why does the following compile under C++11? (I know it won't link.) I would expect the `std::enable_if` test to fail since `1()` is not a function type.

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Func, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_function<Func(Args...)>::value>::type
    delegate(Func, Args...);

int main(void) {
  delegate(1); // << Why does this line compile?
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you be willing to write up how to use it correctly? Or point me to a link?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to SFINAE on?

Comment: I was trying to get `delegate` to only be callable when `Func` is a function (preferably function pointer) that can be applied to `Args...`. I think I wanted `Func *` as the type of the first parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Func` is `int`, `Args` is empty, so `Func(Args...)` is `int()`, i.e., "function of `()` returning `int`".

Anything that `is_function` returns true for can't be the type of a by-value function parameter, so it's not obvious what you want to do.

> I was trying to get delegate to only be callable when `Func` is a
>   function (preferably function pointer) that can be applied to `Args...`

Use expression SFINAE for that.

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args>
auto delegate(Func f, Args... args) -> decltype(f(args...), void());
```

Depending on what you actually want to do, you may want to `std::move` `f` and `args`.

Comment: Small comment - I would imagine OP to desire to return the function return value from the delegate. So likely `decltype(f(args...));` (pure speculation on my part, of course).

Comment: I actually want `delegate` to return `void`. The above works great though, thanks. :) Out of curiosity, why is it `void()`?

Comment: Simply because `decltype` needs an object to deconstruct it's type. `void()` serves as an object of type void. But out of curiosity, why do want sfinae at all? What's wrong with plain function like I've shown in my answer below?

Answer (score 3):

The code you have written will always yield true. You probably meant `std::is_function<Func>...`

Though not sure, it seems like you do not need `enable_if` at all, and you'd better of with a simple

```
template <class R, class... ARGS>
R delegate2(R (*fun)(ARGS...), ARGS...);
```

However, if I am wrong and `enable_if` is a key to success in your case, here is how you can do this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename Func, typename... Args>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_function<std::remove_pointer_t<Func>>::value>::type
    delegate(Func, Args...);

void check(int);

int main(void) {
  delegate(check, 10); // << good line compiles
  delegate(10); // << this bad line does not

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @T.C., see my updated answer - it would work with proper checking call.

Comment: @T.C., I've long ago stopped asking why. On any rate, I have updated the code to a better one.

Comment: My first attempt at this did something like `delegate2`. It unfortunately requires the types to match exactly - so if `fun` takes a `long`, an `int` (literal or otherwise) can't be passed, but has to be explicitly cast. I was hoping to find a delegate call to either do the conversions or otherwise help the types match.

Comment: @oconnor0, makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Based on this comment:

> I was trying to get delegate to only be callable when `Func` is a function (preferably function pointer) that can be applied to `Args...`

you're using the wrong type trait. To check if `Func` is callable with `Args...`, you need to construct an expression that would actually call an instance of `Func` with those arguments. For that, there's `std::result_of_t` (in C++14, it becomes SFINAE friendly):

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args,
    class R = std::result_of_t<Func(Args...)>>
R delegate(Func, Args...);
```

Or, in C++11, just write that out with `decltype` and `declval`:

```
template <typename Func, typename... Args,
    class R = std::declval<Func>()(std::declval<Args>()...)>
R delegate(Func, Args...);
```

Comment: `result_of` is the wrong thing to do unless you want and will use the full might of `INVOKE`.